# SQL get first value of lowest Id

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

How can I get the price of the lowest Id grouped by x?

```
Id    Price    Group
1     $2       A
2     $1       A
3     $5       A
4     $5       B
5     $4       B
6     $3       B
```

The price of the lowest Id of group A is $2 
The price of the lowest Id of group B is $5

Desired result:

```
Group FirstPrice
A     2
B     5
```

I am guessing I have to use CASE WHEN X but I am new to this and can not find a solution to this problem.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select min(t2.id) from t t2 where t2.group = t.group);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Group ORDER BY Id ASC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT Group, Price
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 1;
```

If you implement it, you will find that this is the most appropriate code. If you want to  get the price of the highest Id, just do 'Id desc'.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer you a solution like this

```
SELECT price AS Price, MIN(id), `group` FROM `your_table` GROUP BY `group`
```